# How do I delete a project in IBM Watson Studio?

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson

I had a project which was running into a lot of errors, so I tried to start from scratch by deleting all the services and the project.  Now, the project won't delete because it can't find the cloud object storage thing to clean up.  Clearly, it was a mistake to delete the cloud object service before deleting the project, but now it seems I'm stuck with this project forever.  Does anyone know how to delete the project in spite of its old cloud service object no longer existing?

I tried deleting the project, and I expected the project to be deleted.  Creating additional cloud storage instances and attempting to associate them with the old project seems to do nothing.

Comment: First, many cloud service are not deleted immediately, but kept around for 7 or more days for resource reclamation. In Watson Studio, what steps did you perform? Have you looked into the IBM Cloud console to find the resources?

Comment: In Watson Studio (or Cloud Pak for Data -- I can't really tell), I used the left side navigation menu and went down to Services > Service Instances and then deleted everything in here.  Then I went to Projects > All Projects, but it wouldn't let me delete the desired project.  I am not sure about looking into IBM Cloud console to find the resources?  I definitely deleted the original COS associated with this project, and I can't find it anywhere.  The project won't delete because it keeps getting hung up on not being able to delete the COS.